# CSS positioning multiple tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I have an issue with my css bootstrap.
I have a web page with multiple tables, they must be side by side.
but my css mess up everything :/

The real issue is, i can't put different css attributs on different table. Every table have the same attributs (it's printed in a loop)

my page should be like:

> [table]   [table]   [table]
>
> [table]   [table]   [table]
>
> [table]

But it goes like :

> [table]   [table]   [table]
>
> ............................[table]
>
> [table]   [table]   [table]

( '.' are spacing)

my bootstrap tables attributs :

```
table {
  background-color: #646569;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.table {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

my html table :

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-responsive sortable'>
```

Can someone help me or give me a tip ? ty ! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't float them. Use `display: inline-table;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your html if you wrap each table in a bootstrap column class it should fix your problem like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
   <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive sortable'>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you do this you can remove the `float:left;` from table and `width: 30%;` and `max-width: 30%;` from your .table class.

Your CSS will be like this instead:

```
table {
  background-color: #646569;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```